# One counterCache incrementing, one not - despite identical code for both

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am developing a basic forum system and have used three counter caches in it.

Two are for categories (Containers of threads), which have a `reply_count` and a `thread_count`, and the last is for the post itself which has a `reply_count`.

A thread is made from multiple `ForumPost`s, where one is a thread (`is_thread` = `true`) and the rest are replies (`is_thread` = `false`).

A part of my `ForumPost` code looks like this:

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'ForumCategory' => array(
            'counterCache' => array(
                'thread_count' => array('ForumPost.is_thread' => 1),
                'reply_count' => array('ForumPost.is_thread' => 0)
                // The line above is the one not working
            )
        ),
        'Thread' => array(
            'className' => 'ForumPost',
            'foreignKey' => 'forum_post_id',
            'conditions' => array(
                'ForumPost.is_thread' => 0
            ),
            'counterCache' => array(
                'reply_count' => array('ForumPost.is_thread' => 0)
            )
        ),
    );
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Reply' => array(
            'className' => 'ForumPost',
            'foreignKey' => 'forum_post_id'
        )
    );
```

While this works for the most part, I have noticed one piece of strange behaviour: Threads will increment a category's thread count, but replies will not increment category's reply count, although they do increment a thread's reply count.

I'm still getting used to CakePHP's ways of going about things like this so I might have missed something obvious but I've been pondering over this for a while - any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Edit

The following statement is being executed:

```
UPDATE ... SET `ForumCategory`.`reply_count` = 8  WHERE `ForumCategory`.`id` = 0
```

Comment: Have you debugged this a little bite? Are the appropriate SQL queries being genereated? If so, what do they look like? Have you tried removing the other associations to check whether there's a conflict?

Comment: I didn't realise I could check which queries are generated - I'm analysing the queries now since there's quite a few and some of them are pretty long, but at a glance it seems like it's trying to update the category with ID 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised that it was due to the fact that I wasn't setting the `forum_category_id` for replies to avoid redundancy, but CakePHP uses that value for inserting.

I've had to start making it set the `forum_category_id` on all replies, too, which is a small sacrifice I suppose.